# Export to individual Excel Spreadsheets

Tags: reporting-services

I am currently working on a simple report in Microsoft Report Builder 3.0 but it needs to be exported to Excel and sent to different vendors.

Is it possible to Export a report into individual Excel Spreadsheets, not pages of one Excel Spreadsheet?

Or if this is not possible, what would the best approach be?

Comment: Are you saying your report has multiple pages, each of which need to go to separate excel files?

Comment: Yes, it is a report that contains differing information for different vendors, it's a template really. 

Yes, each of the pages in SSRS would need to be on a different document.

Comment: I don't know - but I would think you'd have to split those pages out into separate reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done after you have deployed your report to a Report Manager or SharePoint portal - it's called a Data Driven Subscription:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150.aspx